# Why does my Spring Controller direct me to the wrong page?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am writing my first Spring 3.0.5 MVC app and am confused about why my controller mappings aren't doing what I expect.

I have a VerifyPasswordController that is called after a user tries to log in by entering his name and password.

```
// Called upon clicking "submit" from /login
@RequestMapping(value = "/verifyPassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ModelAttribute("user")
public String verifyPassword(User user,
        BindingResult result) {

    String email = user.getEmail();
    String nextPage = CHOOSE_OPERATION_PAGE; // success case
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        nextPage = LOGIN_PAGE;
    } else if (!passwordMatches(email, user.getPassword())) {
        nextPage = LOGIN_FAILURE_PAGE;
    } else {
        // success
    }
    return nextPage;
 }
```

I can verify in the debugger that this method is being called, but afterwards, the `verifyPassword` page is displayed rather than the `chooseOperation` page.  The console output of WebLogic seems to show that my mapping are correct:

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/chooseOperation] onto handler 'chooseOperationController'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/chooseOperation.*] onto handler 'chooseOperationController'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/chooseOperation/] onto handler 'chooseOperationController'
```

Here is the ChooseOperationController:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("leaveRequestForm")
public class ChooseOperationController implements PageIfc, AttributeIfc {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/chooseOperation")
    @ModelAttribute("leaveRequestForm")
    public LeaveRequest setUpLeaveRequestForm(
            @RequestParam(NAME_ATTRIBUTE) String name) {
        LeaveRequest form = populateFormFromDatabase(name);
        return form;
    }

    // helper methods omited
}
```

I welcome any advice, particularly "generic" techniques for debugging such mapping problems.  BTW, I've also tried to "redirect" to the desired page, but got the same result.

servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.engilitycorp.leavetracker" />

    <beans:bean id="leaveRequestForm"
          class="com.engilitycorp.leavetracker.model.LeaveRequest" />

</beans:beans>
```

The constants:

```
String LOGIN_FAILURE_PAGE = "loginFailure";
String LOGIN_PAGE = "login";
String CHOOSE_OPERATION_PAGE = "chooseOperation";
```

Comment: Hi, can i see your servlet-config xml file and the value of your constants (CHOOSE_OPERATION_PAGE, LOGIN_PAGE) ? Maybe, it's a problem with your viewResolver configs

Comment: I've edited my post and added the requested info.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, the string that you are returning is the jsp's name(see your internal resource view), if you want redirect to other controller, you should return "redirect:controllerPath", you should check which is the final value of nextPage if is CHOOSE_OPERATION_PAGE value.

Comment: I would be happy if chooseOperation.jsp were displayed.  I have verified in the debugger that "chooseOperation" is returned from verifyPassword().

Comment: One question, can you enter to /chooseOperation from the browser?

Comment: Entering http://localhost:7001/LeaveTracker/chooseOperation?name=sam works.  Entering http://localhost:7001/LeaveTracker/chooseOperation causes a Error 400--Bad Request.

Comment: 400 error is because RequestAttribute isn't optional, try `redirect:chooseOperation?name=sam`; as value of CHOOSE_OPERATION_PAGE,

Comment: Ah, no.  name=sam is a parameter/value pair determined at run-time.  I can hardly make it a compile-time constant.

Comment: But, is required, looks: `public LeaveRequest setUpLeaveRequestForm(@RequestParam(NAME_ATTRIBUTE) String name)` add an optional value and try redirect again..

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the mapping for the other controller i.e., ChooseOperationController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(/chooseOps)
@SessionAttributes("leaveRequestForm")
public class ChooseOperationController implements PageIfc, AttributeIfc {
        //your controller logic
    }
```

And then when you are directing to the success view specify the complete path to know that it has to refer to a different controller.

```
String CHOOSE_OPERATION_PAGE = redirect:chooseOps/chooseOperation;
```